# reference a json field name that contains a dot

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, typescript

I am trying to reference a field from the JSON in Angular

```
{  "elements": [
    {
      "LCSSEASON.IDA2A2": "351453",
      "LCSSEASON.BRANCHIDITERATIONINFO": "335697"
    },
    {
      "LCSSEASON.IDA2A2": "353995",
      "LCSSEASON.BRANCHIDITERATIONINFO": "298931"
    },
    {
      "LCSSEASON.IDA2A2": "310935",
      "LCSSEASON.BRANCHIDITERATIONINFO": "282654"
    },
    {
      "LCSSEASON.IDA2A2": "353967",
      "LCSSEASON.BRANCHIDITERATIONINFO": "353966"
    },
    {
      "LCSSEASON.IDA2A2": "355294",
      "LCSSEASON.BRANCHIDITERATIONINFO": "355293"
    }
  ]
  }
```

In the HTML Template, I want to print the element - elements.LCSSEASON.IDA2A2
But having 2 dots in key is causing issues in below code

Any ideas and suggestions??

I cannot change server JSON Output as its legacy application and I have no control.

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of items">   <li>  {{item.LCSSEASON.IDA2A2}}  </li> </ul>
```

Comment: try `{{item['LCSSEASON.IDA2A2']}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

access the property using square brackets like this

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of items">   <li>  {{item['LCSSEASON.IDA2A2']}}  </li> </ul>
```